# Asynchronous JQuery TreeView with multiple levels of loading in MVC 3 not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3, jQuery, jquery.treeview.js, and jquery.treeview.async.js to load and create a treeview asynchronously.  It is a two level treeview with PartTypes being the top level and then Parts being the second level.  I have the following TreeViewNode class

```
public class TreeViewNode
{
    public TreeViewNode[] children { get; set; }

    public string classes { get; set; }

    public bool expanded { get; set; }

    public bool hasChildren { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is

```
public ActionResult PartTypes(string root)
    {
        var nodes = new List<TreeViewNode>();

        if(root == "source")
        {
            var partTypes = ris.PartTypes.ToList().OrderBy(pt => pt.Name);

            foreach (var partType in partTypes)
            {
                nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode {
                        text = partType.Name,
                        id = partType.Name,
                        hasChildren = true
                    });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var parts = ris.Parts.Where(p => p.PartType.Name == root).ToList();
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                nodes.Add(new TreeViewNode {
                        text = part.SerialNumber,
                        id = part.SerialNumber
                    });
            }
        }
        return Json(nodes);
    }
```

The jQuery code for loading is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#navigation").treeview({
    url: '/Parts/Part/PartTypes/',
    ajax: {
        type: 'post'
    }
    });
}
);
```

and the HTML is simply

```
<ul id="navigation" class="treeview"/>
```

When the page loads all the Part Types load and they load expanded.  No parts load even if you click the individual part type links.  How can I get the Part Types to load collapsed and then load the part names when you expand one of the part types.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you are using the correct javascripts;

jquery-treeview-async-0.1.0.js and jquery-treeview-1.4.0.min.js

Could you check this, because this could be the issue?

Comment: I ended up going with jstree as it had better documentation and I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try to add [HtppPost] on top of the Controller

```
[HtppPost]
```

public ActionResult PartTypes(string root)

Comment: This very well could be the answer, but since I decided to switch libraries due to better documentation I can't really test the answer and mark it as correct.